# How can I use jasmine with a server-side typescript project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jasmine

I have a project that contains modules for both the server and client of my application, which are each built using webpack. I'm using Karma with Jasmine to test my client (which uses Angular) and I would like to use Jasmine to test the server, which is written in typescript, too.

Unfortunately, the only guides that I could find online used jasmine-node (which to be untouched for the past few years) instead of jasmine-npm. Can anyone suggest a way that I can use Jasmine, or an alternative, for testing within my project?

I've tried writing a `jasmine.json` file, or editing the one generated by jasmine with the `init` cli command, however this doesn't seem to work with typescript files.

At the moment, my project's structure is like so:

```
├── client
│   ├── karma.conf.js
│   ├── protractor.conf.js
│   ├── src
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── webpack.config.js
├── server
│   ├── src
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── webpack.config.js
└── node_modules
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for this as well. I'm surprised that finding information on this is so hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its definately possible to use jasmine for your server side tests. Follow these steps and you'll be fine:

1) In your package.json add the following dev dependencies:

```
"jasmine": "latest",
"jasmine-core": "latest",
```

2) Setup your `jasmine.json` so that it will include all files you want to run tests on, etc.

```
{
  "spec_dir": "dist/dev/server/spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "unit/server/**/*[sS]pec.js"    
  ],
  "helpers": []
}
```

3) Add `unit.ts` that will bootstrap your testing process:

```
const Jasmine = require("jasmine");

let j = new Jasmine();

j.loadConfigFile("./jasmine.json");
j.configureDefaultReporter({
    showColors: true
});
j.execute();
```

Now all you have to do is compile and run your resulting `unit.js` in nodejs.

Comment: Do I understand correctly; I should compile unit.ts to a separate artifact to run for testing, as jasmine doesn't directly support other languages?

Comment: Jasmine is meant to run your tests written in js. The same way as node.js is running programs written in js code. The idea here is to write a small ts program to bootstrap jasmine and testing process.

Comment: Any tips on methods to compile with some sort of preprocessor (as you do with karma on the client side)?

Comment: You can compile it the same way as you do with the rest of your project (I assume its in typescript) - using tsc directly or from gulp/grunt.